Is it bad practice to have tables inherit from a parent table to reduce the number of join tables?
In the database I'm building I have many entity tables (users, videos, books, games, etc, etc) that can all be related and potentially have lots of additional data attached to them (comments, links, meta data, etc, etc).
Because every entity can have comments you can't just store the parent_id as a foreign key on the comments table. So you need a join table for every entity and their comments. This quickly adds up to a lot of join tables. Not to mention that the entities themselves can be related.
It might not be a problem to have lots of join tables, but it annoys me. The idea is to make a parent entity table and have all entities reference this table. Now all non-entity tables can just store a reference to the entity instead, and a single many-to-many join table can join all the entities.
I'm sure that this is terrible design. But I don't know why? What could go wrong?
For this database I'm using MySQL but the question is general. Here's some pseudo code for the schema.
table entities
    id

// entity tables
table user
    entity_id references entitites.id

table movies
    entity_id references entities.id

// child tables of entities
table comments
    comment_id
    parent_id references entities.id

// join table connecting entities 
table rel_entities
    entity_id_1 references entities.id
    entity_id_2 references entities.id



Have you considered a comment on a movie and a user to be different entities? I.e. instead of a general comments table, use separate tables: movie_comments, user_comments, etc

You tell that first instance of first entity may refer to second instance of second entity. But the entity names imply that at the same time some third instance of second entity may refer to some forth instance of first entity. I.e. the relation direction in your system makes sense. Whereas the scheme you tell about the relation direction is not mentioned at all. This may be a problem..

You need to clarify what comments are and what the relationships are. If this is about USERS making COMMENTS about MOVIES, then the data model is simple: USERS has zero or more COMMENTS, MOVIES has zero or more COMMENTS. The COMMENTS table is a many-to-many relating MOVIES and USERS, which makes queries easy and natural to write.

The COMMENTS table is then like this: COMMENTS (ID primary key, USER_ID references USERS, MOVIE_ID references MOVIES, COMMENT_TEXT, COMMENT_TIMESTAMP). If you want to restrict users to just one comment per movie, then you can add a UNIQUE(USER_ID,MOVIE_ID) constraint

This allows you to answer questions like what comments did a user write about a movie, what movies did a user comment on, how many users commented on a movie last month etc

If you also allow users to comment on other users, then you need to add a separate USER_COMMENTS table with similar content: USER_COMMENTS (ID primary key, COMMENTING_USER_ID references USERS, COMMENTED_USER_ID references USERS, COMMENT_TEXT, COMMENT_TIMESTAMP)

@AlbertGodfrind I know this can be solved with a join table. But you would have to set up a join table for every type of relationship. The question is about whether it's bad practice to make every entity generic so that you can use a single many-to-many table for any entity relation and so that you can use the entity_id as a foreign key on a single comment table. There should be no reference to the movie table, just the entity table. The comment table wouldn't know which other entity table it will be joined with.

What you're asking about is the concept of normalization.  Here is a quick overview, but more in-depth reading would probably be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description All that said, the problem you are going to run into with your proposed schema is very poor query performance.  The query optimizer is going to struggle to come up with good plans when the data skews based on the entity type you are working with.

Let's see the generated SQL.
